# Navigation drawer default fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am novice developer and I´m integrating Navigation drawer in my app with android-support v7 and I have one  question. When I start the app the main layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

and this is my main activity:

```
drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Fragment3();
                    break;  
                case 3:
                    fragment = new Fragment4();
                    break;
            }

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = 
                    getSupportFragmentManager();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

            drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

            tituloSeccion = opcionesMenu[position];
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tituloSeccion);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
        }
    });
```

How can I set default fragment like main layout of the app? Thank you

Comment: You can find my answer in the post below
[Set Initial Fragment on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133600/set-initial-fragment-on-startup/34856256#34856256)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If it is ok for you to load the default fragment every time your activity is created, you can put a `FragmentTransaction` in `onCreate()`

Looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1());
    tx.commit();


}
```

If you want a more sophisticated way of doing this (for example switching to a different fragment when you go back to the main activity), you can use an `Intent` with extras determining the fragment in `onCreate()`, where you just put your default fragment in the `defaultValue` upon loading the extra:

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 1);
switch(position){

    ...

}
```

Comment: I spent 5 hours trying to figure this out, so simple when you have got the know how. Thanks, this has saved me further hours of struggling..

Comment: my first fragmnet 0 th position fragment loading every time even moving another activity to main view how to solve

Comment: This solution will go back to the default fragment when the user change the orientation of the phone, for example. You should check if the fragment is not already set as in the answer from @sorianiv and only do the transaction when the fragment is null

Answer (score 18):

Put this at the end of onCreate() in Main Activity.

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
 }
```

Comment: Gives me **Cannot resolve method selectItem(int)**.@Jemshit Iskenderov

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in the XML, if that's what you mean. You do it in the onCreate of your activity. For example:

```
if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame) == null) {
  selectItem(0);
}
```

where selectItem is the method you use to select fragments in your drawer, as in google's example https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html, and 0 is the position of the default fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in oncreate:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = new HomeFragment();                                                              
//HomeFragment= fragment class to launch that
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Helps, it is working

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    ,new YourClass())
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Add some description, the logic would be much helpful more than just a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android Studio bottom navigation template:

1. Go to app/src/main/res/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml
2. Change "app:startDestination" to the fragment you want to be displayed on load.

Hopefully, this helps less experienced people like me using the template.

Answer (score -6):

Add a default case in your switch code.

```
    @Override 
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;  
            case 3:
                fragment = new Fragment4();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
```