# How to set a fragment as default fragment for BottomNavigation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Bottom Navigation in my MainActivity.java with 3 fragments.
I want to set one of my fragments as default to open automatically when app starts.
how can i do that?
this is my Main Activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
private Fragment fragment;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();



    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.intros:
                    fragment = new IntrosFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.menus:
                    fragment = new MenusFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.infos:
                    fragment = new InfosFragment();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });


}
}
```

and this is one my fragment for example(they're all the same):

```
public class IntrosFragment extends Fragment {


public IntrosFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intro, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.introtv);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/naskh.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation drawer default fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296531/navigation-drawer-default-fragment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that `savedInstanceState` is null the first time your activity is created to perform code only on first launch. And you can set whichever navigation item you'd like to be selected using [`setSelectedItemId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int)).

Note that `setSelectedItemId()` will trigger your `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, so you should put this code after your call to `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()`.

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.infos); // change to whichever id should be default
    }
```

Comment: its working but i have a problem with tabs when by default first fragment is set Now if i am again click on same tabview then my Top tabview visibility is gone why and other data is there i am using bottomNavigationview with tabviewpager

Answer (score 4):

if you use navigation in one line:

> mobile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation
...
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home"
...
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: In onCreate() of your container activity, put

```
// Default Fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameContainer, new HomeFragment())
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `BottomNavigationView` library there is not a definition of a default fragment to be presented, it gives you total control of which fragment is visible by setting it programmatically as Ben pointed out.

I have implemented this not far ago and I believe you are facing the back press problem, which you probably want to go back to the "default" fragment. In my case I implemented an `interface` which is called `onBackPressed` of the activity, once the user hits the bask press just call the following method to set the "default fragment" as selected

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItem(R.id.myDefaultTabID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void setDefaultFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, YOURFRAGMENT.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

And call `setDefaultFragment()` after `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.